# How to build a list from a subset of lists

Tags: r

If I have a list of df  `lst` which has 4 dfs; `AB, CD, EF, GH`. Now I want to build another list `lst2` with only `CD, GH`. How can I build this sublist?

Comment: `lst[c('CD', 'GH')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
lst2 <- lst[c("CD","GH")]
```

or

```
lst2 <- subset(lst,names(lst) %in% c("CD","GH"))
```

Comment: what if I only want the fist 5 row of each df? how could i do the sebset?

Comment: @Stataq Then you can use `lapply(lst,head,5)`

Comment: If I want to get a sub from AB:EF, how should I write the codes without listing all df names?